# Knime BigData Local Environment & findspark

Tags: pyspark, knime

I'm just wondering: is possible to access the [BigData Environment Node](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.bigdata.spark.local.node.create.LocalEnvironmentCreatorNodeFactory2%23Create%20Local%20Big%20Data%20Environment) launched in Knime?

I have a node in a Knime workflow. From outside Knime, I wrote a Python script using [findspark](https://github.com/minrk/findspark) but ... it doesn't seem to detect it.

Any example or proposal to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean you would like to access big data environment created by this node or?

Comment: Yes @ipazin, this is the case. I would like to access this hadoop node (provided by Knime) from external applications (python script for instance). Do you know url, ports in order to be able to connect (HDFS, Hive etc.) Thank you in advance?

Comment: Hello again. Any comment about the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive is accessible while Spark and HDFS are not. You can connect to Hive via JDBC with port which is randomized upon node execution. Information about it should be in the first output port - DB Session.